# .htaccess and multiple conditions

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

For this displaying

```
website.com/city-name
```

I am using this `.htaccess` rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?skill=$1 [L,QSA]
```

and it's working.
Now I would need to add this friendly URL:

```
website.com/applicant/12 #(12 is applicant's ID)
#or
website.com/applicant/12-john-doe #(id + name)
```

Could you help me, please, with this conditions for `.htaccess`? I am not unfortunately very familiar with `.htaccess`.

Thank you

**EDIT:** What I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?skill=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^applicant/(.*) index.php?id=applicant&applicant_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

When I comment out the 4th line, the last rule is working (but doesn't work `website.com/city-name`). How to merge these two rules?

**EDIT2: bump, anybody who would help me with?**

Comment: Belongs on http://do-it-for-me-plz.stackexchange.com

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Oh man, please, calm down...

Comment: I'm completely calm. Thanks for adding what you tried. This is a much better question now.

Comment: When you comment out the 4th line it is working because the 4th line catches **all** requests and it never comes to line 5. Put it at the end.